# how to change the request timeout time

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an `API` that in development environment takes more than `1 minute` to return, however, always timeout in `60s`, how can I change the `timeout` default (by `postman`, it returns normally, even if it takes more than 1 min, so it is not a backend )?
I tried a solution I found on the internet, however, with values ​​less than 60s it works, but even putting a high value, timeout when it hits `60s`.

```
@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Inject(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) protected defaultTimeout: number) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(timeout(300000));
  }
}
```

Comment: cant you put:
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

Comment: @Fiehra I did not understand

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@NgMoule({
....
   imports: [HttpClientModule],
   providers: [{provide: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, useValue: 180*1000}] <- should be provided in the same module where you already have HttpClientModule
})
export class AppModule {...
```